# Parsing CSV file with moving one cell to a different row

Tags: python, parsing

I am trying to parse a file by some identifier in a col2 and create a new dataframe with this identifier in a new column with the rows below it.  Then do this again with the next identifier.

My currenct code is:

names = ["[NR n1 TX DC calibration]", "[NR n1 RFIC Gain Calibration]"]

identifier = "dummy"

for f in files:

```
df = pd.read_csv(f, sep='\,', header=[1], engine='python')
# print(df_parsed)

for i,r in df.iterrows():
    if df.at[i, "Item"] in names:
        identifier = df.at[i, "Item"]
        # print(identifier)
        for i,r in df.iterrows():
            df['Info'] = identifier
```

Sample Original Data:
[original data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ozfe1.png)

Formatted Data:
[formatted data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1fdLe.png)

Currently this code can add the identifier to all the rows but I want to only add it to the rows specified below the identifier until another identifier is found.

I have to do this type of way since rows beneath the identifier are not consistent

Comment: It's hard to understand what you're trying to do. Show your code and what doesn't work about it. For example, show the desired output. Read this https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: The input and desired output format is in the example screenshot.  I don't really have the code written yet since I don't know which path to go to implement what I want.  I've used csv_reader and readlines before but don't know how to do exactly what I want for this data.

Comment: Not sure what to suggest -- you need to make it easier to help you. I can't load a picture of your data. You should probably use `pandas`, start by loading your CSV into there. Or spend a few minutes making your question easier to understand.

Comment: Okay I've updated with some code.  Where I am stuck is how to check when the identifier changes, how to update the identifier that is used for the new DataFrame.

Answer (score 0):

Sample of the answer that worked for me.  I created a list with the identifier I am looking for and then add it to the following rows that match until it find another identifier.

```
for i, row in df.iterrows():
    if df.at[i, "Item"] in identifier_lst:
        identifier = df.at[i, "Item"]
    df_temp.at[i, 'Calibration'] = identifier
    df_temp.at[i, 'Item'] = df.at[i, 'Item']
    df_temp.at[i, 'Measured'] = df.at[i, 'Measured']
    df_temp.at[i, 'Min'] = df.at[i, 'Min']
    df_temp.at[i, 'Max'] = df.at[i, 'Max']
```